# Why does running latex with a4paper or 210 mm × 297 mm followed by dvips result in bounding-box width 596 pt rather than 595 pt?

Tags: paper-size, dvips, unit-of-measure, dvi-mode, points

Various source on the Web (e.g., http://www.prepressure.com/library/paper-size) specify the A4 paper size as 210 mm × 297 mm or 595 pt × 842 pt. Using 1 pt = 25.4 mm / 72, the width 210 mm ≈ 595.275590551 pt is closer to 595 mm than to 596 mm both in terms of absolute and relative errors.

The relative errors to the ideal ratio ⎷2 are |297/210 - ⎷2|/⎷2 ≈ 0,000051019 = 0,0051019 % and |842/595 - ⎷2|/⎷2 ≈ 0,000645226 = 0,0645226 %, respectively.

Now run `latex` followed by `dvips` on

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}%% either use the option a4paper or:
%\setlength\paperheight{297mm}%
%\setlength\paperwidth{210mm}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

In the resulting Postscript file, we see

```
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 596 842
…
%%DocumentPaperSizes: a4
…
{ pop << /PageSize [595 842] >> setpagedevice }
```

The width of the bounding box is different from what the Web sources usually specify. Also notice that the relative error to the ideal ratio is |842/596 - ⎷2|/⎷2 ≈ 0,001033708 = 0,1033708 %, which is worse.

So why 596 and not 595? Any rationale? Is this still within the (coarse) accuracy of TeX or is there a bug there? Any chance to improve this?

Using Knuth's point, which is 1/72.27 in  = 25,4 mm / 72.27 ≈ 0.351459804 mm, we'd arrive at the paper size of ≈ 597.507874016 pt × 845.046850394 pt, so I hypothesize that it's NOT Knuth's points which are meant in the Postscipt file.

PS. Looking into `topoints(integer i)` pointed out by David in https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/dvipsk/output.c?revision=61701&view=markup, we discover that the code there, `i += 65780L; return (i / 6578176L)*100 + (i % 6578176) * 100 / 6578176;`, does not correspond to its comment. Namely, the code does NOT always perform ⌈i/65781.76⌉, as can be witnessed by i=1: the code yields (65781/6578176)·100 + (65781%6578176)·100/6578176 = 0·100 + 65781·100/6578176 = 0 + 6578100/6578176 = 0, whereas it should yield ⌈1/65781.76⌉ = 1. Overflows start with i=2147417868. If we wish (for whatever reason) to upround the results of the division, we have to mind this:

---

Let ∈ℕ₀,  = /ℎ ∈ ℚ₊, >1, ,ℎ ∈ ℕ₊.  Task: compute ⌈/⌉.

Claim: For integers ,⩾1 we have ⌈/⌉ = ⌊(+-1)/⌋.

Proof.
If | then LHS = / = ⌊/+(-1)/⌋ = RHS.
Otheriwse, ∤. Then LHS = ⌊/⌋+1 = ⌊(-1)/⌋+1 = ⌊(-1)/+1⌋ = RHS. QED

So ⌈/⌉ = ⌈ℎ/⌉ = ⌊(ℎ+-1)/⌋.

---

As 65781.76 = 1644544/25, we'd have to replace the function body with `return (25LL*i+1644543)/1644544;`.  This requires `long long` from C99 and avoids overflow only if `long long` is wider than `int`. With a little more math, we can avoid overflow in C89 while using only arithmetics on `int`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/78127921.

However, I see no overly convincing reason to upround.  For simple rounding of i/65781.76 towards the nearest integer, we have to compute the rounding of 25i/1644544, e.g., via `return (25LL*i+822272)/1644544;`, since the integer division `/` in C rounds down.

Comment: A4 is _exactly_  210 mm × 297 mm it is not that that is an approximation to the exact size based on root 2.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In this case, the relative error is still bigger: |842/596−297/210|÷(297/210) > |842/595−297/210|÷(297/210).

Comment: so it should be 595.3  but tex arithmetic is pretty inaccurate and actually its better to be too big than too small in case you clip stuff too tightly

Comment: Not sure about Postscript, but in TeX, 1pt = 1/72.27in (roughly, in fact 1in = 72.26999pt due to fixed point precision).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Or the paper doesn't fit into the box, just in case a top-end printer would actually *cut* the paper to the size needed.

Comment: "so I hypothesize that it's NOT Knuth's points which are meant in the Postscipt file. Indeed, 1 TeX point \ne 1 Adobe point (aka "big point", or bp). TeX uses the convention 1in=72.27pt, whereas Adobe (who created PostScript...) uses the 1in=72bp convention.

Comment: @Skillmon I added the last para concerning Knuth's point.

Comment: @Mico Right, which is the the same as the standard typographical point.

Comment: well the resulting PDF has 595 842, and the postscript contains later on `/PageSize [595 842]`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, TeX's arithmetic is inaccurate, and I never expected this to make it to the level of the first decimal digit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I also see `/PageSize [595 842]` in the Postscript output.

Answer (score 5):

## This is a **non answer** but too long for a comment.

Assuming you have a site default set to be A4 the test document produces

**pdflatex:** Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)

**latex/dvipdfmx:** Page size:      595.28 x 841.89 pts (A4)

**latex/dvips/ps2pdf:** Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)

So you see, the issue is with dvips rather than latex.

As latex has not specified a page size, you get the site default which comes from a file installed something equivalent to

`/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.ps`

which says

```
@ a4 210mm 297mm
@+ ! %%DocumentPaperSizes: a4
@+ %%BeginPaperSize: a4
@+ /setpagedevice where
@+  { pop << /PageSize [595 842] >> setpagedevice }
@+  { /a4 where { pop a4 } if }
@+ ifelse
@+ %%EndPaperSize
```

so the 595 is asserted and you see that at the end of the ps file (and that gets used by ps2pdf which is why the above shows 595 exactly)

which still leaves the question of where the 596 in the bounding box comes from...

Ah the comments in the dvips.c source (`output.c`) say

```
/*
 *   Convert scaled points to PostScript points.  This is the same
 *   as return (i * 72 / (65536 * 72.27)), which is the same as
 *   dividing by 65781.76, but we want to round up.
 */
```

and 596 is 595.273 rounded up....

in theory you can change this with

`\special{papersize=592.48pt, 841.89pt}`

but I can't make it give 595pt  it jumps between 591 and 596....

Comment: (1) I'm unsure why the authors would want to round up. If the page size is clipped per later PostScript command at 595 pt anyway, there's no point in offering a larger bounding box. Or is there? 
(2) The actual code is a bit complicated. I'm unsure why, after `i += 65780L`, they return `(i / 6578176L)*100 + (i % 6578176) * 100 / 6578176`, as they could simply say `i/65781.76f` (which might be imprecise, but it's usually way more precise than TeX's own computations) or `100LL*i/6578176` or, better, `25LL*i/1644544`. Perhaps, avoiding overflows and staying precise?

Comment: @AlMa1r the code in the C and the config code to overlay the page size from the config may well be different people decades apart. this is all _very_ old (and I didn't trace it all which is why I put that not an answer banner at the top) but it may help someone track further,

Comment: For uprounding, `i += 65780L; return (i / 6578176L)*100 + (i % 6578176) * 100 / 6578176;` is wrong. Running it on i=1 yields (65781/6578176)*100 + (65781%6578176)*100/6578176 = 0*100 + 65781*100/6578176 = 0 + 6578100/6578176 = 0, whereas the result should be ⌈1/65781.76⌉ = 1. Overflows start with i=2147417868. A trivial repair would be replacing the procedure body with `return (i*25LL+1644543LL)/1644544LL;`; this assumes `long long` from C99. However, I'm unsure what uprounding is good for. Without such knowledge, I'd suggest rounding to the next integer: `return (i*25LL+822272LL)/1644544LL;`

Comment: Perhaps, there might be a mathematical reformulation of this that requires neither C99 nor risks an overflow from multiplying by 25. As for who wrote this, the earlierst commit to the tug repository is from *karl*, whoever he might be (Karl Berry?): https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/dvipsk/output.c?revision=1485&view=markup .

Comment: @AlMa1r yes Karl Berry, but I think this goes back to Tom Rokicki 15 years before that commit. Feel free to edit this answer, comments like the above are easy to miss if left in comments.  Also you could raise a bug at texlive (easiest way is to mail tex-live  at tug.org)

Comment: I edited my question with the data from the comment; feel free to edit your answer or my question or both. As for bug raising, I'm afraid I'm out of time for this now (I still have to deliver on testing your solution for issue 288 in babel, and today is March 8 …). But bug raising should be done because there are two big errors: (1) code not doing what the comment says and (2) unclear/unconvincing intent of uprounding.

Comment: I've just submitted a bug report to the tex-live list. Many thanks again!